# Objective-C can't convert NSNumber to int

Tags: objective-c, arrays, integer, int, automatic-ref-counting

I have a simple code that will iterate through an array of integers but when I tried using a "for in" loop, it said I needed to have an object so I used an NSNumber but in order for my code to work, it had to be an int so after the loop, I had it convert the NSNumber to an int.  It gave me another error saying I need to declare the variable _*strong for it to work so I did that but now it gives me these errors: "Incompatible pointer to integer conversion sending 'NSNumber **_strong' to parameter of type 'int'" and "Implicit conversion of 'int' to 'NSNumber *' is disallowed with ARC"  Here is the code that gives an error:

```
for(__strong NSNumber *i in factors) {

        i = [i intValue];
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've already declared "`i`" as an Objective C object (specifically a NSNumber object).

If you want to do the conversion, declare a *separate* and different variable, e.g.

```
int j;
```

and set your integer to that, like:

```
j = [i intValue];
```

Comment: in other words, the runtime has no problem converting an NSNumber to an int. It's the *assignment* of that int back to the NSNumber variable it is complaining about.

Comment: One reason why it's always wise to try to use meaningful variable names.